# Ambiguous intersection notation: $\mathcal G(\mathbb R^{[0,1]})\cap C([0,1])$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am attempting to understand a theorem from my lecture's notes, however it seems to me that the notation used there is ambiguous and therefore unclear.

The full statement and proof:

[image]

Where $\mathcal G(X)$ stands for open sets in the space $X$, $C[0,1]$ is the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, $\mathcal U(y,\epsilon| C([0,1]))$ is the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the point $y$ with respect to the space $C([0,1])$

Now $\mathcal G(\mathbb R^{[0,1]})\cap C([0,1])$ is confusing as one is a set system and the other is a set of functions, i.e. is it $\{A\cap C([0,1]): A\in \mathcal G(\mathbb R^{[0,1]})\}$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: What does $\mathcal{G}$ denote?

Comment: @JustinBenfield oops, sorry, completely forgot to clarify notation, will do

Comment: The only intersection that is meaningful is the one where we take each open set from $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ and intersect it with the space $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$. The point of the theorem is that the resulting set will still be open in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ and that this can be done for any open set in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: Would then $\{A\cap C([0,1]): A\in \mathcal G(\mathbb R^{[0,1]})\}$ be the correct interpretation for the left side of the statment?

Comment: Not that I edited my question, as I realized multiple flaws in my thinking, the proper definition of the intersection notation is the only remaining ponit that is unclear now.

Comment: I believe so. I do have one other question: Em I correct in thinking that $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is the space of functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. The point of the theorem is this: Given the (unmentioned) topologies for the space of functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to itself (I suspect you've established some sort of natural choice for these topologies previously in the notes). If you take any open set in the space of functions with codomain $\mathbb{R}$ and intersect that with the (smaller) space of continuous functions the result is an open set in the topology for the latter space.